# Using cast() to transform a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a data.frame like this

```
> x <- data.frame(A=c('a','a','b','b'), B=c(1,2,3,4))
> x
  A B
1 a 1
2 a 2
3 b 3
4 b 4
```

I'd like to transform it into

```
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4
```

It should be a simple operation, but I can't figure out how to do it.
The closest I've got to is `cast(x, . ~ A)` which at least doesn't
fail with "undefined columns selected" but it's still not what I want.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sure you don't want to `melt` first?

Comment: There's already only one variable with measured (numeric) values, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also been struggling to understand `cast` recently. Your desired output shows the values `1` and `3` on the same line. But your input doesn't provide that information. Adding an `id` column solves the issue.

```
library(reshape2)

x <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 1, 2), A=c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), B=c(1, 2, 3, 4))

dcast(x, id ~ A, value.var="B")
#   id a b
# 1  1 1 3
# 2  2 2 4
```

Comment: thanks, I thought the order was implicit in the row order of the original data frame

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
data.frame( tapply(x$B, x$A, list))
```

Result:

```
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain the values ​​of B in the same order as in x, you could try this:

```
data.frame(split(x$B, x$A))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know `split`. This will do it.